# Where to ask a question about deploying a set of services on a local machine in order to test them as if they were in cloud?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am building several [micro]services which in production will be deployed on independent set of resources (Cloud instances within different autoscaling groups). The services are being written in different languages/stacks: Node.js and .NET mostly. I'd like to test them out locally but with configurations that are as close to production as possible (ideally, even the API endpoints should be as if they are real).

I don't whether there are ways to do it. I think, Docker might be the thing that I'm looking for but I may be wrong.

Will this kind of question be appropriate on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com? Do I need to polish it before posting so that it's specific enough? Software recommendations is definitely off-topic on SO, and I feel my question falls into that category, but Software Engineering might be different.